# Openai Gym version 0.10.3, How to add a super mario environment? Scoreboard folder not available

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

Did everything as given in this link https://becominghuman.ai/getting-mario-back-into-the-gym-setting-up-super-mario-bros-in-openais-gym-8e39a96c1e41

But in latest gym version 0.10.3, scoreboard folder has been removed and import gym_pull also not working.

Any work around?? other than switching to previous version of gym?